# how to init guice if my running class is junit?

Tags: java, junit, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, guice

I'm writing an API module.

while developing I use junit to run the code

however eventually some other modules will use my API.

I want to use dependency injection pattern

a) Where should be my main entry where I init all the dependencies or global utils?

b) I thought it be neater using guice injector,

but where should I init it?

Comment: Have a look at frameworks like Jukito that manage the Guice lifecycle for you in tests.  And try to avoid injection in unit tests if you can help it, just use direct constructor calls.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're trying to do. I find, with [`BoundFieldModule`](http://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/testing/fieldbinder/BoundFieldModule.html) and the [`@Bind`](http://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/testing/fieldbinder/Bind.html) annotation in Guice 4.0, that it's generally easiest to just use Guice directly. For example:

```
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public final class TestMyInjectableCode {
  @Bind @Mock @SomeAnnotation Foo myFoo;
  @Bind @SomeAnnotation String myAnnotationString = "some constant";

  @Bind(lazy = true) @ShouldDoSomeThing Boolean shouldDoSomeThing = false;

  @Inject Provider<SystemUnderTest> systemUnderTest;

  @Before public void setUpInjector() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    Guice.createInjector(BoundFieldModule.of(this)).injectMembers(this);
  }

  @Test public void test_ShouldDoSomeThing() {
    shouldDoSomeThing = true;
    SystemUnderTest sut = systemUnderTest.get();
    assertEquals("expected value", sut.getValue());
  }
}
```

Comment: You also need to add the `com.google.inject.extensions:guice-testlib` dependency to your project.